# Hibernate, MySql, Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a problem calling a MySql function with a varchar return type in hibernate.I have searched but couldn't get the answer.

How can i do the same.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("call schema.get_next_number(:v_type, :v_incr, :v_inscomp)")
            .setParameter("v_type", "policy")
            .setParameter("v_incr", incr)
            .setParameter("v_inscomp", "");
    query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: And what is your problem with it? Any error message?

Comment: What do your procedure?

Comment: @Jens the error is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: PROCEDURE kwft_ins_agency.get_next_number does not exist

Comment: I am not calling a procedure it is a function whose signature is as foolows CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `get_next_number`(`v_type` varchar(20), `v_incr` int(1), `v_inscomp` varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET latin1

Comment: Maybe the schema is not correct.

Comment: How should i solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use CallableStatement and register varchar type as output type

```
CallableStatement statement = session.connection().prepareCall(
    "{ ? = call schema.get_next_number(?) }");
statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
statement.setString("v_type", "policy");
//set other parameters
statement.execute();
String result = statement.getString(1);
```

Comment: the ? withing get_next_number(?) should it be just one or as the number of parameters. for my case; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `get_next_number`(`v_type` varchar(20), `v_incr` int(1), `v_inscomp` varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET latin1. I tried using session.connection() isn't available in hibernate 4

Comment: the ? withing get_next_number(?) should it be just one or as the number of parameters. for my case; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `get_next_number`(`v_type` varchar(20), `v_incr` int(1), `v_inscomp` varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET latin1. I tried using session.connection() isn't available in hibernate 4

Answer (score 0):

This how i have solved the issue,`Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select get_next_number(:v_type, :v_incr, :v_inscomp)")
                .setParameter("v_type", "policy")
                .setParameter("v_incr", incr)
                .setParameter("v_inscomp", "");
        List result = query.list();